# Use environment variables as default for cmake options

Tags: cmake, environment-variables

I would like to set up a cmake script with some options (flags and strings). For some of the options I would like to use environment variables as a default. Basically, I'm trying to emulate something like `MY_OPTION ?= default` in a Makefile. I tried the following:

```
project (Optiontest)

option(MY_OPTION 
       "Documentation"
       $ENV{MY_OPTION}
       FORCE)

message("value: ${MY_OPTION}")
```

I called this in the following way:

```
$ cmake -DMY_OPTION=ON .
value: ON
$ cmake -DMY_OPTION=OFF .
value: OFF
$ MY_OPTION=OFF cmake .
value: OFF
$ MY_OPTION=ON cmake .
value: OFF
```

My problem is that the last line should be ON as well.

For bonus karma: I would actually prefer three levels of preference. The value of `-DMY_OPTION` should be used if given. If not, the value of a set environment variable `MY_OPTION` should be used. If this is also not set, a constant should be used. I guess, I could use a bunch of nested if statements and somehow check if the variables are set, but I don't know how and I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FORCE` is (as of CMake 3.0.2) [not a valid parameter for `option`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/option.html).

This is the primary source of problems. CMake will interpret the string `FORCE` as the desired initial value of the option in absence of an environment variable. The [usual contrived rules](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html) for string-to-truth-value-conversion apply, resulting in the option being set to `OFF` by this call.

Second, you need to account for the fact that the environment variable is not set. Your current code misses to handle that case properly. `$ENV{MY_OPTION}` will evaluate to the empty string in that case. If you evaluate the set values in both the cache and the environment, you can enforce any behavior that you want.

In general, you should think about what you actually want here. Usually, `FORCE` setting a cached variable is a bad idea and I would not be surprised if you found your initial argument for doing this flawed after some careful reevaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe value of MY_OPTION cached in CMake cache? Do you try to clean cmake cache after third call `MY_OPTION=OFF cmake .`?

Comment: Yes, the value is cached. Is there a way to overwrite the value in the cache with the environment variable if it is present? I thought FORCE would do that.

Comment: I reproduced your problem, cleaning the cache don't help for me.